# how to get only info about hdd name and type without another info

Tags: powershell

if i put this into variable

```
$testt= Get-PhysicalDisk | Select FriendlyName, MediaType
```

and echo it, how to get rid of this FriendlyName and MediaType, i only want to see my hdd and type, without this grep fields

```
 FriendlyName               MediaType
------------               ---------
WDC WD10PURX-64D85Y0       HDD      
GIGABYTE GP-GSTFS31240GNTD SSD      
TOSHIBA DT01ACA100         HDD
```

But i want output to be

```
    WDC WD10PURX-64D85Y0       HDD      
    GIGABYTE GP-GSTFS31240GNTD SSD      
    TOSHIBA DT01ACA100         HDD
```

Comment: Read this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-physicaldisk?view=windowsserver2019-ps and then change what is in your `Select` list.

Comment: its not problem in that, problem is that i get output with that text FriendlyName and MediaType..I only want to see name and type, without that text, so i will edit post to see what i refers to

Comment: Try with  'echo $testt | FT -HideTableHeaders'

Comment: You edited your question after I posted that comment.

Comment: @spikey_richie how to get rid empty spaces when output a commaaaaand

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by running the Powershell command with the format table option included e.g.

`Get-PhysicalDisk | Select FriendlyName, MediaType | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders`

See [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.1) for more details on the `Format-Table` cmdlet.